# Не могу писать в терминал VC code

Tags: localhost, visual-composer

После запуска localhost приходится перезагружать VC Code, что бы можно было писать в терминал, можно ли с помощью какой-то команды или еще чего-то исправить это?

Comment: VC это что? [Visual Composer](https://visualcomposer.com/)? Если я не угадал, то [поправьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1506114/edit), пожалуйста, метку в вашем вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Звучит как проблема с расширениями. Попробуйте добавить в параметры запуска --disable-extensions. Если помогло - отлично, запускайте вскод в нормальном режиме и по 1 выключайте расширения, пока не заработает. Если не помогло - возможный решением станет переустановка вскода, пишите по результатам.

Comment: добавил параметр - не помогло. ctrl+c нажимаю и терминал обновляется

Comment: ну пробуйте переустановить вскод, ничего страшного